# SQL. Perfomance of count on many columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the amount of distinct values of every column in a table. So, I wonder, if using   a query like

```
select count(col1), count(col2),.., count(colN) from table;
```

will scan the whole table N times to get all these counts? Then will it be better to use objects/procedures that concrete DBMS has to create array 1..N with value amount for every column and count values by looping table records and incrementing array elements?
I understand that this is totally dependent to a DBMS realization, so I'd like to know it specially for MySQL (but info about other popular systems is interesting too).

Comment: Barring some really stupid DBMS, any sane engine should at worst do this in a single pass, and some _may_ be able to use indices (unlikely unless every column is covered).  I don't know what advantage you think you'd get by 'manually' looping table records - SQL is supposed to be used in a 'set' manner, and things like cursors tend to just slow it down.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this moment. The advantage I thought I'd get is just removing useless full-table scans. Of course it would be very stupid of developers to make DBMS scan one table N times, just wanted to assure, that it is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do:

```
select count(distinct col1),
       count(distinct col2),
       ...
from   table;
```

and the database should just do a single full-table scan to calculate this.